# Changing stylesheet for a partial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, stylesheet

I have a Movie class in my Rails app, and I have a "_movie.html.erb" partial that displays the movie's title, its overall rating, and a brief summary.

I want a stylesheet to apply to this particular partial, but nothing else in my app.

How do I do this?

In case it helps, I don't want to do some type of CSS classing on the partial instead, because the stylesheet is a huge, gargantuan mess that's not created by me and that may be updated in the future. (For example, let's say that the partial is trying to mimic the way RottenTomatoes displays a movie.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think partials are associated with specific stylesheets.

You're probably going to have to wrap the partial in something like:

```
<div id="movie">
  <!-- partial code -->
</div>
```

Then you can just use a separate stylesheet like movie.css, which you can link in addition to the main stylesheet to do your styling (which can also go in the main stylesheet). There isn't really a way around using any id's or classes that I'm aware of.

Comment: How do I make sure the movie.css stylesheet applies only to the div with id="movie"? Do I have to add "#movie " to every selector in movie.css?

Comment: Yes, so styling a p tag inside of your movie section would be #movie p {css:rule;}. Styling a li item inside of a ul inside movie would look like #movie li {css:rule;}. Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all of the CSS in to one sheeet - it's better for performance reasons.

Specificity determines what CSS applies to what elements, so just style everything like so

```
#movie p { } 
#movie table { }
#movie h1 { }
```

and that css will only apply to content within #movie div.
you can include 2 stylesheets if necessary to keep content separate, but it's not worth it unless you're talking thousands of lines of css, which is unlikely given its just for 1 div.